# RecyclerView.ViewHolder unable to bind view with ButterKnife

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-adapter, butterknife

I'm using `ButterKnife` to bind my views on my `ViewHolder`. My code is below:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<DataObject> data;

    public MyAdapter(List<DataObject> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.row_header_view) View rowHeaderView;
        @BindView(R.id.row_header_view_text) TextView headerTextView;

        @BindView(R.id.row_data_view) View rowDataView;
        @BindView(R.id.row_data_view_text) TextView rowDataTextView;
        @BindView(R.id.row_data_view_detail_text) TextView rowDataDetailTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason in my `ViewHolder` all of the `BindView`'s do nothing. They are all null. I can confirm with certainty they are in my layout. What is wrong with my above code? I have used it as per the documentation listed here:

http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/#reset

Is there anything else required? I'm using `ButterKnife` version:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
```

If I add the below line:

```
rowHeaderView = view.findViewById(R.id.row_header_view);
```

It's able to get the view properly. But how does this make sense? Isn't `ButterKnife` usable where `findViewById` is usable?

Comment: Do you have the apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1' dependency?

Comment: Yes, it's in my gradle file.

Comment: @KVISH can you apply plugin like this `apply plugin: 'android-apt'
`in your `module.build` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure that if you have use `ButterKnife` library to use this way

**build.gradle** file of Project

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
  }
}
```

Then, apply the `'android-apt'` plugin in your `module-level build.gradle` and add the Butter Knife dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
}
```

Comment: `@Nullable` refers to fields that are optional. Mine are all there. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @KVISH  can you apply plugin like this `apply plugin: 'android-apt'` in your module.build ?

Comment: Ahhh yes. that was missing. I fixed it. If you update your answer I will accept it.

Comment: @KVISH glad to help you.

Answer (score 23):

**Update for October 2016:** You probably don't need apt and the android-apt plugin anymore. Version 2.2 of the Android Gradle plugin has an annotationProcessor configuration that you should be using instead.

In Android studio 2.2 onward, just add these on your build.gradle module :

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```